# C# StyleBundle doesn't include linked files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stylebundle

VisualStudio 2019, I have two projects in a solution which essentially need to share a single CSS. I have the physical file added to project A, and then I added the same file as a "link" file in Project B. This way only 1 file needed to be updated.

I have my bundleConfig set up properly, but the linked file is never included in the bundle in Project B.

I didn't see any options for doing so in the bundle config. Any other option besides duplicating a physical file?